# Shortest formal proof that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[1 - (a-1)^n\right]$ diverges for all $a\in [0,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone provide the shortest formal proof that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[1 - (a-1)^n\right]$ diverges for all $a\in[0,1]$?

Comment: "ratiotest".  See, I left out a space to make it shorter.

Comment: I didn't mean it to be that way.

Comment: I know, I guess I'm being glib.  Have you tried the ratio test?

Comment: Try to show that for $1 \geq a > 0$ the term $(a-1)^n$ converges to $0$.

Comment: can you formalize it as an answer below

Comment: "ratio test", by the way, leads to an inconclusive result.

Comment: It is practically impossible to show that a proof is the shortest possible. And anyway, "formal" means different things to different people as well as to different automated proof checkers. To some people, @MatthewLeingang's first comment is a very short and perfectly formal proof. Can you describe what sort of proof you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[1 - (a-1)^n\right]\neq0$$

Comment: Nice! Any other proof?

Comment: this is the shortest!

Comment: I'll be waiting for others' answers if there are any.

Comment: sure, I'll be waiting too.

Answer (score 0):

The $n^\text{th}$ term is $\geqslant 0$ for all $n$, and $\geqslant 1$ for all odd $n$, therefore the $n^\text{th}$ partial sum is $\geqslant n/2$ for all $n$.